# Как записать в файл ошибки выполнения команды в консоли?

Tags: ubuntu, консоль, логирование

Ну вот к примеру :

```
/usr/bin/php -f ffmpeg.php
```

Как мне ошибки записать в файл?

Так же вопрос ещё в том чтобы если данные выводятся не сразу - в файл так же добавлялись эти данные.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте перенаправление вывода `2>`

```
/usr/bin/php -f ffmpeg.php 2> error.log
```

Comment: Ну так вот я так и делаю. 
На выходе файл создается, но пустой

Comment: Разобрался)) Я же чуть чуть другую команду запускаю и там было у меня ffmpeg -f
Поменял на ffmpeg -i

Comment: А нет.. Не разобрался.. 
Если указываю -i - то в log пишется тупо phpinfo, а если вообще убираю - опять файл пустой. 
В консоли выводится всё.

Comment: Уже исправил и ответил.